# Как добавить загрузку Windows в grub?

Tags: linux, grub, fedora, dual-boot

У меня есть жесткий диск, на котором установлена Windows. Я попробовал установить Fedora на новый жесткий диск.
Теперь я могу выбирать в Bios диск, с которого будет происходить загрузка и таким образом загружать Windows или Fedora. Однако, хотелось бы увидеть в загрузчике сразу 2 ОС и выбирать между ними.

Я пробовал делать так:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Однако Windows не определяется. Вывод выглядит так:

```
[root@localhost default]# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-45450d3854b84d8ba40c055b725c1f51
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-45450d3854b84d8ba40c055b725c1f51.img
done
```

Что я делаю не так и как мне добавить выбор двух ОС в загрузчик?

**UPD:**

Fedora грузится в EFI, а Windows в Legacy

Comment: `os-prober` установлен?

Comment: Я 2 часа как пользуюсь Linuxom. Что это за зверь и с чем его едят?

Comment: похоже, что установлен

Comment: если кратко, то это утилитка/скрипт, которую использует grub для поиска ОС отличных от linux... дело в том, что в вопросе уже готовый ответ: `grub2-mkconfig` должен был бы найти сторонние ОС из коробки, так что осталось разобраться, что пошло не так... в принципе можно и вручную было бы вписать всё в конфиг, но для grub2 это относительно нетривиальная задача, готовое решение вряд ли кто-то выдаст, а самостоятельно после пары часов дойти практически невозможно... как я понимаю, `os-prober` win также не выдаёт в списке? жёсткий диск с оным в принципе виден?

Comment: Жесткий виден. Похоже на то, что у меня федора  грузиться в UEFI режиме, а винда в Legacy. Я пока еще не разобрался, что есть что до конца.

Comment: `os-prober win` результатов не возвращает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По простому - никак.

`Grub` не умеет загружать одну ОС в `Legacy` а другую в `Efi` режиме.
Загрузчик `Windows` тоже так не может.

Однако можно перевести загрузчик `Windows`([руководство](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024558/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)) в `Efi` и тогда `Grub` без проблем найдет обе ОС(но успешного перевода никто не обещает).

Альтернативные варианты загрузки:

1. Использовать другой менеджер загрузки - [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)
2. Чаще всего современные UEFI(BIOS) позволяют выбирать с чего грузиться по какой нибудь горячей клавише. В моем случае во время загрузки можно нажать F11 и выбрать жесткий, с которого грузить систему.