# grub не видит Windows 10

Tags: linux, администрирование, grub

На днях поставил на свой комп SSD-шник. Поскольку я использую Windows для Ил-2 и аналогичных целей, то решил разместить на SSD-шнике именно Windows. А в качестве основной ОС у меня Fedora-32.

Раньше, при загрузке, grub выдавал меню, в котором был и Linux и Windows. Но сейчас я не могу обновить меню, так как *os-prober* не видит Windows. Вот так:

```
$ sudo os-prober
[sudo] пароль для lary: 
$
```

И всё... :-(

Пытался явно прописать пункт меню в файле */etc/grub.d/40_custom* но кончилось это плохо - меню исчезло вообще! Во время загрузки вместо меню выскакивает какая-то строка, начинающаяся с *Error* (которую я прочитать не успеваю) и загружается Linux.

В связи с этим второй вопрос - как можно увидеть лог работы *grub*? Ведь когда он работает, файловые системы ещё не смонтированы!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить загрузку Windows в grub?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823252/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83-windows-%d0%b2-grub)

Comment: @mik.ov там написано "По простому - никак". Не очень утешительно... Но причина называется такая: винда и линукс грузятся в **разных** режимах Efi/Legacy. Тогда вопрос конкретизируется: как изменить режим загрузки винды? (Или линуха). Это в bios-е  делается?